# CSS List Styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with a list of words from a file. I need help getting rid of the whitespace in the box using the CSS code below. Is it a margin error? I haven't text aligned to the centre either. I can't seem to figure out the CSS error. I'm hoping to keep the dimensions of the box the same just the words to fit in from the left but text-align: left doesn't solve it either. Please Help! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your code and your list items were ul's so I changed them to li's and changed the parent ol to a ul and then styled list style none and removed the padding then fixed the width a bit.

The html won't be very responsive due to static widths so you might want to work more on that but I've fixed the issue you described.

```css
 #app {
  display: table;
  height: 80%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.search-header {
  display: inline-flex;
}
#item-list {
  height: 350px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-left: 55px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.search-text {
  white-space: normal;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.search-box {
  height: 15px;
  width: 400px;
}

#search-box[placeholder] {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.allButtons{
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS search filter</title>
      </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="search-header">
        <div class="search-text"> Find: 
        <input id="search-box" />
        <button type="button" class="allButtons" span onclick="var input = this.previousElementSibling; input.value = ''; input.focus();"> Clear </button></span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul id="item-list"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var itemList = [
    "a",
    "able",
    "about",
    "account",
    "acid",
    "across",
    "act",
    "addition",
    "adjustment",
    "advertisement",
    "after",
    "again",
    "against",
    "agreement",
    ];

const itemContainer = document.getElementById("item-list");
const searchInput = document.getElementById("search-box");

// Trigger function every time search text is changed
searchInput.onkeyup = (event) => {
  filterBySearch(event.target.value);
};

// String to render HTML list item
const itemHTML = (item) => `<li>${item}</li>`;

// Function to render filtered list
const filterBySearch = (query = "") => {
  var renderHTML = ``;
  // Generate HTML for filtered List
  itemList.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      renderHTML += itemHTML(item);
    }
  });
  // Display updated HTML on screen
  itemContainer.innerHTML = renderHTML;
};

// Load the list of items
filterBySearch();
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You beat me to it